# Custom background theme support not being applied

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've added theme support for a custom background to my WordPress theme, as below, but the background colour is not actually being applied (note that the options are showing correctly in admin though).

According to [the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds) "When the administrator sets custom values for the theme, WordPress generates an extra style sheet in-line with the HTML headers." However, this is not the case.

The `<body>` tag is declared as `<body class="home blog logged-in admin-bar customize-support">`, with the promised `custom-background` class neither declared in the header nor applied to the `<body>` tag.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Here is how I am adding custom background support.

```
$ps_background_defaults = array(
    'default-color'          => '000000'
);
add_theme_support('custom-background', $ps_background_defaults);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I hadn't saved the custom background settings, and once I'd done that everything was fine.

This does seem like an issue with the core to me, as the default is ignored, and I am off to do some research on Trac now. I'll update with a ticket if one is opened.